# I'm having this error when compiling my code: value with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Team numbers are found by dividing the employee id by four. If 4 divides the employee id evenly, then that employee is part of team 1. For the other cases, a remainder of 1 places that employee on team 2, etc.

I got this result when I run the Code

```
SELECT  EMPLOYEE_ID, MOD(EMPLOYEE_ID, 4) AS "TEAM"
```

---

```
100 0
101 1
102 2
103 3
104 0
105 1
106 2
107 3
```

but I need to get the following result:

```
100 1
101 2
102 3
103 4
104 1
105 2
106 3
107 4
```

Comment: MOD(EMPLOYEE_ID, 4)+1

Comment: *"I'm having this error when compiling my code: value with SQL"* - what error? What code are you compiling? (SQL isn't compiled.) Also, your caps lock is on.

Comment: Then just Add One!?

Answer (score 4):

Trivially, you may just add one to result of the `MOD` function:

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    MOD(EMPLOYEE_ID, 4) + 1 AS "TEAM"
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: No, you didn't answer, you commented.  And I didn't see your comment until after I posted.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh this is a question and answer site. Comments are for requesting clarification, and although I agree sometimes the answer is so trivial it hardly seems worth posting as an answer, you can hardly expect people not to answer just because you have left a comment.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Nikhil would have been in the right had I _poached_ his comment, some time after he left it, and then passed it off as my own work.  But, that's not what happened :-)